# How to locate the function being applied on password

Tags: javascript, proxy

I am thinking of taking up ethical hacking as a hobby. So, I installed Burp Suite Community Edition and set it up with Firefox. I opened Instagram and tried to login with these details (just for testing):

```
Username: admin

Password: 123456
```

However, when I intercepted the request in Burp, although the username was still admin , the password had been encrypted to something else. This means that somewhere in the code of the website, a formula tells Firefox how to convert 123456 to that string. How can I find this 'formula'?

Comment: https://github.com/FeezyHendrix/Insta-mass-account-creator/issues/140

Comment: @0xec That's helpful. But, it's kinda just the code for me to copy paste. Could you assist in how to locate the said code so I can learn and use the method on other websites too

Comment: You can Google for the string `PWD_INSTAGRAM_BROWSER`.

Comment: @0xec I meant that if I want to work out the encryption mechanism for some other website, say Microsoft, how do I proceed?

Comment: @FitzWatson most websites don't do anything like this. The answer will also depend on the website, but will generally require you to read through the JavaScript.

Comment: @multithr3at3d I tried Microsoft. It does this. Here's what I thought would help me: I found the id and name of text box that contains the password and it's division . Tried to locate that Id&name in js files of website to see where the contents of the text box are referenced to. Found 0 matches. Any idea why this didn't work and what might actually work?

Comment: @FitzWatson if it's some frontend framework, that type of operation may be abstracted away and make it hard to search on such criteria. Maybe try looking for crypto/hash related functions, or words like "password", "encrypt", etc.

Comment: @multithr3at3d If they obfuscated the code, wouldn't those words be gone?

Comment: @FitzWatson possibly, but it depends on the particular application. There still could be a way around that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109008/discussion-between-fitz-watson-and-multithr3at3d).